# C++ #include <iostream>

Tags: c++

I'm a complete newbie to C++. I'm trying to write a simple c++
program but I got an error message. I suspect this is due to me
accidentally deleting some .h files on my mac which might have ruined
my Clang compiler. How can I fix this? Do I need to reinstall Xcode or
change a compiler?

Error message from terminal:

```
    192:desktop ivanlee$ gcc test.cpp
    In file included from test.cpp:1:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:215:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:90:
    In file included from /usr/include/wchar.h:70:
    In file included from /usr/include/_types.h:27:
    /usr/include/sys/_types.h:32:10: fatal error: 'sys/cdefs.h' file not found
        #include <sys/cdefs.h>
             ^
    1 error generated.
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    return 0;
    std::cout << "Hey";
}
```

Comment: [Read a good book about C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: If you really did delete system header files, you're going to want to fix that first, *before* you proceed any further.

Answer (score 2):

At first I ought to recommend you [the definitive stackoverflow c++ books list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Read these books and get your skills grow. This also will prevent questions like this.

Your question needs very-very basic knowledges and answers may be too long and your problem can be solved by many different methods.

I can tell you one but you should not ask questions like this.

**Answer**

Your code contains a mistakes:

1. `return 0` before your other instructions (it should be the last). Now your program will just do nothing.
2. You should always compile C++ code with C++ compiler. `gcc` is not a `c++` compiler but `c` compiler - use `g++` instead.
3. Even if you correct 2 errors above, your `std::cout` call may fail because it does not flush the stream. You should also add `<< std::endl` to this call.

Answer (score 0):

Execute

```
g++ test.cpp -o out
```

Instead of

```
gcc text.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
run Terminal
execute gcc -v
```

Read the info and copy the include path.  Copy it to your IDE that allows you to add the include path.

Mine, for an example, is:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1

Comment: This is not related to `gcc`. The `g++` compiler should be used.